# If formula to return either the lead company name or contact on a related object

Tags: formula, formula-field

Good Afternoon All,

I need some help with a formula.

Aim – Create a text formula which returns either the Lead company name or the contact company name based on criteria.

Criteria – If the lead isn’t converted then return the lead company name; if the lead is converted then return the contact account name.

Fields to use are ;

BrightTALK__Lead__r.Company
BrightTALK__Contact__r.Account.Name
IsConverted

Really hoping you lovely people can help

Looking forward to your response

Comment: What formulas have you tried and what were the issues you ran into?

Comment: I tried the following formula, but that returns either lead company name or the contact account name. I havent however included any if statements and this is where i am struggling BrightTALK__Lead__r.Company+ " " +BrightTALK__Contact__r.Account.Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IsConverted is a checkbox field values will be true or false, so you should be able to write it like this:

```
IF(IsConverted, BrightTALK__Contact__r.Account.Name, BrightTALK__Lead__r.Company)
```

Try this:  `BLANKVALUE(BrightTALK__Contact__r.Account.Name, BrightTALK__Lead__r.Company)`

Based on comments try a combination:

```
IF(IsConverted, BLANKVALUE(BrightTALK__Contact__r.Account.Name, BrightTALK__Lead__r.Company), BrightTALK__Lead__r.Company)
```

Looks like this last formula will work:

```
IF(ISBLANK( BrightTALK__Lead__c) || BrightTALK__Lead__r.IsConverted, BrightTALK__Contact__r.Account.Name,BrightTALK__Lead__r.Company)
```

> **BLANKVALUE**    Determines if an expression has a value and returns a
>   substitute expression if it does not. If the expression has a value,
>   returns the value of the expression.

Comment: Hi Jenny B , Thanks for your response, however its only returning Lead company name. 

If this was an excel formula it would be something along the lines of =IF(ISBLANK(B2),A2,B2)

Comment: @DMason updated with another option.

Comment: HI Jenny, that works but what happens when you convert a lead ? Which name does it take ? for eg is it the lead company name or the account.name ?

Comment: @DMason it will always use the first field when it's not blank, when it is blank it will use the second value.

Comment: |But if a lead is converted to a contact, which value will be populated ? I still need that isconverted condition

Comment: @DMason added another attempt lol...

Comment: When i add the if statement it only returns the lead company name and not the contact

Comment: @DMason OK, I think I misunderstood you want both values when it's converted?

Comment: NO, when converted i only need the contact.account name, if lead not converted i need the company name from the lead

Comment: @DMason Cleaning up my comments here and created a chat if you want to continue to discuss http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25461/isconverted-formula

Comment: Unfortunately Jenny, I cant set up an account so unable to join the chat

Comment: @DMason can you describe what object this formula is on and what the 2 fields are? I'm trying to replicate your issue, currently I have a custom object with a lookup to lead and a lookup to contact. I populated both lookups and did the first formula and it seems to work ok for me so I'm probably missing something in your design.

Comment: jenny B- Do you want me to set up a quick Go-To-Meeting or Lync Meeting So you can see the relationships ?

Comment: @DMason yea that'd work.

Comment: Provided details

Comment: @DMason, sorry about that accidentally closed the tab but glad things are working!

Comment: No worries, tweeted you aswell :) thank you Jenny.